# NSTextField label not updating

Tags: objective-c

I will be very short because of this **simple issue**:

(This is a document based app, and i will ***provide just*** the code I have ***the issue*** with)

.h :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Document : NSDocument {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *someText;
}
```

.m :

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        //Some initialization..

        [someText setStringValue:@"Downloading data..."]; //This is not updating !

        //Some others..

    }
    return self;
}
```

***That label is not updating, but why ?? This seem to be a very stupid problem but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong..***

Answer (score 0):

Outlets will not yet be connected when the init method runs. You'll want to move code that depends on nib objects existing to `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Does AppKit have viewDidLoad now? I thought that was only in Cocoa Touch.

Comment: `UIViewController viewDidLoad` has been in iOS since 2.0 came out in 2008.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, but we're talking about Macs here, not iOS. I don't think `viewDidLoad` exists on Mac.